# How to find backlight is managed by which card?

Tags: command-line, ati, backlight

Is there any command in ubuntu/linux which can help me in finding out that which card(intel or ATI card) is managing my backlight?

When I looked at `sys/class/backlight` then I am able to find three different folders/symbolic Links. (acpi_video0,acpi_video1,intel_backlight).

I am new to linux world, so if you think question is too basic then I would appreciate if you could refer me some book/webpage/tutorial where I could update myself quickly.

Comment: The hard way to do this would be manually editing `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness` , `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/max_brightness` and `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` one by one and see which one has effect on system. Also see this wiki for more on changing the values https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight

Comment: It's usually the intel one BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to find which card is in charge of managing your backlight is by looking at the full sys/class path of your devices:

[image]

In my case the `intel_backlight` refers to card0-LVDS-1, where [**LVDS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling) usually refers to your laptop LCD monitor.